# SAP PowerDesigner - alter model with SQL

Tags: powerdesigner

I have a SQL script which fixes/alters the production DB schema (deployed from current PDM).

I need to mirror the same changes to the current PDM.

Is there a way to run the same SQL script *somewhere* within the PowerDesigner so the PDM updates exactly the same instead of doing it manually step-by-step?

Comment: I don't think the "alter" syntax can be reverse-engineered by PowerDesigner. You could restore a backup of the production DB elsewhere, and reverse-engineer it from  PowerDesigner in a new model; open the existing model, and merge the reversed one into the reference one. You can play with the Comparison Options to only show, and apply the relevant differences: for example, unselect all the Comments if you didn't generate them...

Comment: ..yeah. it seems that way. I can't believe this absolutely essential functionality is not there!

Comment: The idea may be that the models serve as reference, with the Archived Model as reference for the previous version. If people start applying modifications with scripts, maybe with direct SQL statements... the scripts cannot be used as a trusted reference of all the changes which have been made...

Comment: Perhaps, but bad practice can be introduced into any system regardless of the functionalities available. Having SQL script based PDM changes available would simplify and speed up development. Let's say you need to update every table in the model and change one common column datatype from varchar(128) to varchar(256). In a PDM where there are over 500 tables a simple SQL update script would save several thousand mouse clicks.